# How can I count the number of transitions from one state to another?

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, counting

I have the following vector

```
[1] 1 3 5 1 1 4 3 4 5 1 1 2 2 3 1 1 2 4 3 4 4 4 1 1 1
```

generated by the following piece of code

```
set.seed(5)
my.matrix = round(matrix(data = runif(n = 25, min = 0, max = 5), ncol = 5),0)
my.vec = as.vector(my.matrix)
```

I know that I can compute the frequency with which every number was sampled and store it in a data frame with

```
freq = as.data.frame(table(my.vec))
```

Suppose now that every number in this vector is a state `S`.

> How can I calculate the number of times all possible transitions from one state to the following state happened?

For instance, how many times `S` went from 1 to 1, and from 1 to 2, from 1 to 3, and so on.

I am trying to calculate a transition matrix, but the only idea I had so far to carry out this task was to use a `for` loop with 16 different `if` statements. This seems like not the optimal path to take.

Comment: You don't need that many if statements... Just create a bidimensional array (a matrix) filled with zeroes and walk along the vector... On each step record the initial and final values (in your example the first step would be from 1 to 3, the next from 3 to 5 and so on...) Find the element of the matrix that corresponds to the initial-final pair (for example matrix[1][3]), increment it by one and take another step... So all you need is one `for` loop and nothing else

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Javier. But how would I _"record the initial and final states"_ ? Again, I only see how to do it using `if statements`.

Comment: The `for` loop will walk you through the array/vector (each iteration will place you on an array element). No need for if. Just read the value you're on, and move on to the next one. I'm not familiar with R, but this is a basic enough construction that can be described in pseudo code. Would a more detailed answer in pseudo code work for you?

Comment: Yes, I think it would help indeed. I'd appreciated if you could write it for me.

Comment: There you go... Sorry I took so long. I'm writing on my cellphone and i'm not the fastest phone typist :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your contribution, Javier. I'll try to code it up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simulated data via `set.seed(101); z <- sample(1:5,size=100,replace=TRUE)`; sorry, I didn't see you had a data-generating function in your question ...

To get all next-step transitions: table of (current) vs (next):

```
table(z[-length(z)],z[-1])

    1 2 3 4 5
  1 4 4 2 3 3
  2 5 4 4 3 4
  3 2 2 2 5 5
  4 4 2 5 6 7
  5 2 7 3 7 4
```

On the other hand, if you only want transitions between *different states*, i.e. between runs (`rle`= "run-length encoding"):

Get the values of each "run" in the data

```
v <- rle(z)$values
```

Construct a table of (current value) vs. (next value):

```
table(v[-length(v)],v[-1])
```

Results:

```
    1 2 3 4 5
  1 0 4 2 3 3
  2 5 0 4 3 4
  3 2 2 0 5 5
  4 4 2 5 0 7
  5 2 7 3 7 0
```

Comment: Hi, Ben. Thanks for your answer, but I think there's a problem with your suggestion. For some reason, it fails to count the transition between the same states. The first 6 elements from your data are `2 1 4 4 2 2`, and as you can see from your result, the count at [2,2] and [4,4] is zero, which is not true.

Comment: @MasonBeau Ben beat me to it, but you should be able to adjust his last line to `table(my.vec[-length(my.vec)], my.vec[-1])`. I think that'll give you what you want.

Comment: Hey, @hmhensen, thank you for your input, but how would that change the fact the code doesn't count transition between equal states? The line of code you wrote is Ben's last line of code but with `my.vec` instead of `v`. No?

Comment: @MasonBeau It is the same. It's actually just Ben's first line of code but with your vector name. The reason Ben's code wasn't including transitions between equal states was because the `rle` function reduced the vector to only unique consecutive inputs. If you don't take that step, the code above using the `table` function will give you the transitions (if you can call them that) between equal states as well.

Comment: Yeah, that slipped me! Only now have I re-read this post. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full example using 1 for loop. The key is to build all possible transitions using expand.grid (note that you need the `unique` command around `my.vec` as some transitions occur more than once).

Once you have that grid, simply step through your vector in a for loop, pull the current and next element, identify the index in the grid that it belongs to and increment it by +1. The code is below.

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(5)
my.matrix = round(matrix(data = runif(n = 25, min = 0, max = 5), ncol = 5),0)
my.vec = as.vector(my.matrix)


result <- expand.grid(unique(my.vec), unique(my.vec)) %>% mutate(count = 0)
for (i in 1:(length(my.vec)-1)){
  currentVal = my.vec[i]
  nextVal = my.vec[i+1]
  result[result$Var1 == currentVal & result$Var2==nextVal,]$count = result[result$Var1 == currentVal & result$Var2==nextVal,]$count +1
}
```

If you want to cut out the rows where the transition never occurs:

```
resultNoZeros <- result %>% filter(count > 0)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your contribution, user1357015. It worked like a charm. I have a follow-up question, though: I see you used `dplyr` to do the trick for you. I don't know it, so I wonder if you know how to change the shape of the `results` dataframe into a "square matrix" to make it look like a transition matrix. The row and column names would be the states, and counting of transitions would sit in the corresponding square (from Si to Sj).

Answer (score 1):

Here's pseudo code that may be of help:

You have a 25 element vector/array. Each element is a number from 1 to 5. For convention, let's call the vector `vec` and assume the elements are indexed from 0 to 24

You need a 2-dimensional array (essentially a matrix), let's call it `m` so that `m[0][0]` is row 0, column 0 (first row, first column). The initial condition is that every coordinate in the matrix has a value of 0

We will be using and re-using two variables on each iteration to determine which cell in the matrix must be incremented. We'll call these a and b. `a` will be each step's "from" value and `b` will be the step's "to" value

> 1. STEP ONE (first iteration of the `for` loop)

Since this is the first element of the array we'll just assign its value (1) to `a` and move on (end the iteration)

> 2. STEPS TWO TO 25

a. Advance to the next element in the vector and record its value (3) in variable `b` at this point, `a = 1` and `b = 3`

b. Locate the matrix element for the first row, third column (something like `matrix[1][3]`) and increment its current value (0) by one so now `matrix[1][3] =1`

c. Before moving on we need to prepare ourselves for the next step so assign `b`'s current value to `a` (now `a = 3` so it's ready to act as "from" on the next iteration). Leave `b` alone for now, as its current value is irrelevant until the next iteration.

d. Go to the next iteration of the `for` loop (move to the next element in the vector (which is 5) and start over at step 2a

(At this point, `b` shall take the current element value (5) so you go to `matrix[a][b]` and increment the current value of that element by one)

Rinse and repeat until you've completed the for loop and you're set

As you can see, you do not need any `if` structures at all... Just a moving pointer that allows you to read an array element's value

There's even more efficient ways to do this but this should suffice